# Javascript Regex - Replace all occurences of matching string EXCEPT any string between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need to replace a string that has has instances inside another but ignore replacing any string if it is inside curly braces.

I have tried the following:

```
str = "replace {replace} test replacesreplace"
str.replace(/{[^}]*}|(replace(s)?)/g, "%")
// % % test %%

str = "replace {replace} test replacesreplace"
str.replace(/{[^}]*}|(replace(s)?)/g, "$1"+"%")
// replace% % test replaces%replace%
```

But I need the replace to look like this: `"% {replace} test %%"`

Can anyone suggest how to do this inside Javascript?

Comment: Is the occurrence always `{replace}` or could it be something more such as `{foo replace bar}` ?

Comment: @hwnd occurence could be `{test replace test test}` so between curly braces is my best bet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function with `String.replace()`. If capture is found, braced stuff is returned, else `%`.

```js
var str = "replace {replace} test replacesreplace";

str = str.replace(/({[^}]*})|replaces?/g, function($0, $1) {
 return typeof $1 != 'undefined' ? $1 : "%";
});

document.write(str);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Saw this format elsewhere but was not quite sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Negative lookahead

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/dZ1eQ8/1)

```
(?!\{)replace(?!\})
```

1. `(?!\{)`: Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match `{` literal
2. `replace`: Matches `replace` string literally
3. `(?!\})`: Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match `}` literal

**Javascript Demo**

```js
var str = "replace {replace} test replacesreplace";
var replacedStr = str.replace(/(?!\{)replace(?!\})/g, "%");

document.write(replacedStr);
```

Comment: This was almost there. -> a string like `"replace {replace replace replace}"` would return `% {% % replace}` which is an undesired effect.